# Autostart regulated by checkbox in C#

Tags: c#, checkbox, autostart

Is there any way for C# windows application to have user-regulated autostart which could be turned on and off on demand? Like, you mark a checkbox and from now on the program starts with Windows, until you unmark the checkbox again? All I could find was tips on how to manually edit Windows registry, but I want the program to have it as a built in function which any user could easily turn on and off.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the Registry in a C# program. Just implement the manual way in code and you have your button. [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) will probably help you.